# Visual Studio C++ 2010 how can __argv be a null pointer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, argv

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Format is straightline.exe <EO records file> <output file>");
        return 1;
    }
    string eoPath = string(__argv[1]);
    //...other stuff ...
}
```

If `__argc == 3`, how can `__argv` be a null pointer?

My debugger is telling me that `__argv` is pointing to `0x00000000` after the program crashed when I was trying to reference `__argv[1]` (and I have verified that `__argc == 3`). This is a minimal program and it happened in the beginning before I did any sort of processing.

Comment: I'm sure I just don't know this, but where is __argv (not argv) coming from?

Comment: Who ever made *any* guarantees about the behaviour of variables starting with double-underscores?

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing that out guys. In fact I was just perusing my code when I noticed that. I used to have to use those underscores as the standard way; I forget exactly why. Something to do with weird Windows/Microsoft/VisualStudio weirdness. Anyway, I have switched to the non-underscore and it is working, thankfully

Comment: Wow, so after this, I was having trouble converting TCHAR* to char*. But amazingly I changed _tmain to simply main, and _TCHAR* to simply char*, and it still runs as normal and now the char* is simply a char*, so everything works now

Answer (score 6):

If this is complied as unicode, then `__argv` will be null, while `__wargv` will contain what you want.  I believe that there is a `__targv` that should contain the command line arguments regardless of unicode or ascii.

But why use any of these if you can just use `argv` passed in as a parameter to _tmain?

Comment: Because of `[w]WinMain`.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer to `__argv` can (and will) be `null` in Unicode configurations.

Comment: and the opposite is true .. in non-unicode apps __wargv is null.

Answer (score 1):

`__argc`, `__argv`/`__wargv` and `__envp`/`__wenvp` are special globals used by the CRT init, you shouldn't ever touch these, rather just stick to the variables passed to your `main`/`wmain`/`_tmain` function, these are derived from the aforementioned globals, and they are guaranteed to be correct, and thanks to Microsofts macro's for the `_tmain` variant, they will also use the correct character encoding (UNICODE vs MBCS/ASCII).

Comment: The `__argc` and `__argv` variables exist so that [programs using `WinMain()` as the entry point can access `argv` and `argc` parameters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126571), since `WinMain()` doesn't pass them to you. The `main()` function of course doesn't have this problem since it provides them in the function signature.

Comment: @Insilico: that article is for **Windows 3.1**, and any `WinMain` based application that needs the command-line should use `GetCommandLine`  to retrieve it (even though it *does* get passed to you, hence the `lpCmdline` parameter of `WinMain`)

Comment: Yes, but it shows that it is in fact documented. While you can use `GetCommandLine()`, it gives you the entire string and not an array of arguments. You can convert it via `CommandLineToArgvW()` but that's only available for Unicode builds. Besides, `__argv` and `__argc` are what's passed to your `main()` function, so it's exactly equivalent.